# how do emit events i.e mouseover, click etc using KonvaJS, Angular 14 and socket.io

Tags: angular, socket.io, konva

I am trying to create a realtime and collaborative canvas which many browsers can connect. I have challenges to emit and use transform, mouseover, click etc.
I created a service

### Service

```
public createCircle(stage: any, layer: any, transformer: any, menuNode: any, color: any, io:any) {
    const circle = new Konva.Circle({
      x: 250,
      y: 250,
      radius: 70,
      fill: color,
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      draggable: true,
      name: 'circle' + Math.random(),
      isSelected: true
    });    
  
    circle.on('mouseover', () => {
      transformer.nodes([circle]);
     // layer.draw();
    //  menuNode.show();
    });
  
    circle.on('click', (e) => {
      e.target.draggable(true);
      menuNode?.classList.add('hidden');
      layer.draw();
      
    });

    io.emit('click', circle);
  
    stage.on('click', (e: { evt: { clientX: any; clientY: any; }; }) => {
      const clickPos = {
        x: e.evt.clientX,
        y: e.evt.clientY
      };
      
      if (!circle.intersects(clickPos)) {
        transformer.nodes([]);
        return;
      }

    });
    

    layer.add(circle);
    stage.add(layer);
    layer.draw();

   // Emit the `createCircle` event to the server
   io.emit('createCircle', {
    id: circle.attrs.name,
    x: circle.attrs.x,
    y: circle.attrs.y,
    radius: circle.attrs.radius,
    fill: circle.attrs.fill,
    stroke: circle.attrs.stroke,
    strokeWidth: circle.attrs.strokeWidth,
    draggable: circle.attrs.draggable,
    isSelected: circle.attrs.isSelected
  });
  
  io.emit('update', circle);
  io.emit('mouseover', circle);
    
  }
```

In my component, I want to create **ngOnit** and **afterView**

### Component

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: '#container',
      width: window.innerWidth * 0.92,
      height: window.innerHeight * 0.9
    });
    this.stage.clearCache();
    this.layer = new Konva.Layer();
    this.layer.add(this.transformer);
    
    // setup menu
    this.menuNode = document.getElementById('menu');
   
    this.stage.on('click', (e) => {
      // when click out, the menu should disappear
      this.menuNode?.classList.add('hidden');
    });

    this.layer.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
      e.evt.preventDefault();
      e.target.draggable(false);
      this.currentShape = e.target.name();
      this.menuNode?.classList.remove('hidden');
      this.menuNode.style.top = e.evt.clientY + 'px';
      this.menuNode.style.left = e.evt.clientX + 'px';
      
    });

    this.layer.on('click', (e) => {
      e.evt.preventDefault();
      this.currentShape = e.target;
      
      if (!this.currentShape?.attrs.isSelected){
        return ;
      }
      
      if(this.currentShape.attrs.isSelected) {        
        this.currentShape.getLayer()?.batchDraw();
        // This is a subscription to the color$ subject. It is used to update the color of the shapes.
        this.color$.subscribe(color => {  
          const shape =  this.currentShape.attrs;
          shape.fill = color;
          shape.isSelected = false;
          shape.id ='selected';
          shape.stroke = 10
      });
      
     }
     // Show the transformer around the selected shape
      this.color = '#ffffff';
    });
 
  }

  
  public findCircleById(circleId: string): Konva.Circle | null {
    const circles = this.layer.find('Circle');
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      const circle = circles[i] as Konva.Circle;
      if (circle.attrs.name === circleId) {
        return circle;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
 
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    
     // listen to the createCircle from socket.io 
     this.io.on('createCircle', (circleData: any) => {
    
      const circle = new Konva.Circle(circleData);
      this.layer.add(this.transformer);
      this.layer.add(circle);
      this.stage.add(this.layer);
      this.layer.draw();
    });

       // Listen for the 'updateCircle' event from Socket.IO
   this.io.on('updateCircle', (circleData: any) => {
    const circle = this.findCircleById(circleData.id);
    console.log(circle);
    if (circle) {
     // update transformer.nodes on circle
      //this.transformer.nodes([]);

       console.log(circle.getTransform);
       console.log(circle._allEventListeners);
      this.layer.draw();
    }
  });
  }
```

### In ngOnit

I have click events on layer and stage for context-menu i.e. right click and for color etc. The problem I encountered, I can't make those events work. I have tried everything, like emitting the circle after events have triggered. I really someone to assist me with this.

```
public createShape(shape: string) {
    this.menuNode?.classList.add('hidden');
    switch (shape) {
        case 'circle':
            this.endPen();
            this.shapeService.createCircle(this.stage, this.layer,  this.transformer, this.menuNode, this.color, this.io);
            break;
    }
```

I used createShape(circle) in html to draw the circle on the canvas. Right now whenever I draw circle, it appears on all browsers but the problem is when I drag the circle, transform, move, or mouseover, right etc. I don't apply to the over browsers.

### Socket.io

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('createCircle', (circleData) => {
    // Broadcast the `createCircle` event to all connected clients except the sender
    socket.broadcast.emit('createCircle', circleData);
  });

  socket.on('updateCircle', (circleData) => {
    // Broadcast the `updateCircle` event to all connected clients except the sender
    console.log(circleData);
    socket.broadcast.emit('updateCircle', circleData);
  });

  socket.on('mouseover', (circleData) => {
    // Broadcast the `mouseover` event to all connected clients except the sender

    socket.broadcast.emit('mouseover', circleData);
  });

  socket.on('click', (circleData) => {
    // Broadcast the `click` event to all connected clients except the sender
    socket.broadcast.emit('click', circleData);
  });

  // update stage with event from konva shapes 
  socket.on('updates', (data)=> { 
    socket.broadcast.emit('updates', data);

  });
});
```